# Is there any integral of $x$ other than $\frac12{x^2} + c$?

Tags: integration, derivatives

I am looking for functions, other than $F(x)=\frac12x^2 + c$, whose first derivative is $F'(x)=x$. Are there any such functions?

Comment: Functions of one variable?

Comment: Where? On a connected subset of $\mathbb{R}$ those are all of them. On a disconnected open subset you can choose different $c$ for each connected component.

Comment: $\int F'(x)\,dx$ is a family of functions that differs only by a constant, so $\frac 1 2 x^2 +c$ is the only solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, if two functions have the same derivative, then the difference of those two functions is a constant.

Thus all the anti-derivatives of $f(x)=x$ are in form of $ (1/2) x^2 +C$

Comment: "... then the difference is locally constant." would be more precise, because sometimes locally constant doesn't imply constant.